# What is the meaning of "just" in "I've just eaten a burrito"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, ambiguity

> I've **just** eaten a burrito.

Would this be correctly interpreted as

1. "I've **recently** eaten a burrito"
2. "I've **only** eaten a burrito"

Or are both valid readings of the sentence?

Why?

In case it isn't obvious, I'm aware of both meanings being valid for *just*.  But does one take precedence over the other here, and if so, what governs this?

An example in context (given by @JamesWebster):

> "What have you eaten?"
>
> "I've just eaten a burrito"

Answer (score 4):

Context, dear boy. What is the context?

The **"only" meaning** can hold if the context is (among others):

- what were you doing when you were supposed to do something else
- what [bad] things you just did
- what do we do

For example:

> "I just said that he was a failure, not that he was a [insert curse word]."
>   "You just need to keep up the good work."

---

The **"recently" meaning** can hold if the context is *what happened in a recent timeframe*:

> "We just lost the football game!"
>   "They just stole my car!"

Comment: "I've only eaten just a burrito." is not a valid English sentence.

Are you sure "He just bought one chocolate bar" cannot mean "He only bought one chocolate bar"?

Comment: Rewriting... I was rushing, so I didn't think hard enough.

Comment: Is the first line to be read in the style of Sherlock Holmes?

Comment: Probably unintentional?

Comment: The edited answer here seems to make even less sense to me than the first.  I can't at all follow what you're trying to say in relation to my question.

Comment: Thanks Maasumi. I do know the formatting was bad but I had school projects to do so I had no time to fix it.

Comment: OK, but I'm asking about which definition of just is implicit in for a specific sentence and you just seem to be telling me what the word just can mean in any context...

Comment: There is ***no*** implicit meaning of "just"  in "I just ate a burrito." You have to know the context first.

Answer (score 2):

As the other answer mentions, it depends on context.

> Would you like a sandwich?
>   No thanks. I've just eaten a burrito.

Here, I would assume that you had recently eaten a burrito.

---

> Would you like a sandwich?
>   Yes please. I've just eaten a burrito.

Here, I would assume that are still hungry because you haven't eaten enough. This however, still seems a little *off*. I'd use "only" in this case anyway.

---

> What have you eaten?
>   I've just eaten a burrito

Here I can't tell. This is ambiguous. Either you are telling me that you have recently eaten a burrito, or you have only eaten a burrito. Without asking more information I think I would *guess* that you recently ate.

Of course, if I then offer you food, you'll probably decline and any confusion will be cleared up.

Comment: What's worse, "I've only eaten a burrito" carries exactly the same ambiguity.

Comment: @SF. I disagree. I would ever use "I've only eaten.." To mean recently. Do you perhaps mean "I've only just eaten..."

Comment: "I'd only eaten my lunch when the alarm rang", and "I'm not breaking my diet! I've only eaten one cookie!"

Comment: You first example doesn't make sense to me (to mean recently). I interpret that to mean e.g. "I had only eaten my lunch, (but not had time to have a cup of coffee), when the alarm rang"

Comment: Yes, or didn't get to do anything else, e.g. I was planning to relax after the lunch. I guess the time shortage and 'fulfillment shortage' may become synonymous in certain contexts.

Comment: Yeah I don't think the only=/=recently really works either to be honest.

Comment: @JamesWebster ."What have you eaten? I've just eaten a burrito" This is what I'm getting at.  Is there a "primary" meaning here?  I'm not sure there is

Answer (score 0):

> I've just eaten a burrito.

means that I recently ate a burrito whereas,

> I've eaten just a burrito.

means that I've eaten only a burrito, and nothing else.

Comment: -1 "I've just eaten a burrito! I didn't eat that giant sandwich!"