# In terms of meaning "recently", what is the difference between just & only?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, ambiguity

**Note**: This post is different to this one [difference between only and just](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/168091/difference-between-only-and-just), which does not talk about the meaning of "recently".

Imagine, there is an appointment at a caffe, I am late for 10 minutes, when I arrive at the caffe, my friend is already in there. I say: "I'm so sorry! I am late". My friend says: "Nah, I am *just* arrived".

In the scenario above, "just" is more appropriate than "only", why?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the meaning of "just" in "I've just eaten a burrito"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/71202/what-is-the-meaning-of-just-in-ive-just-eaten-a-burrito)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correction: "Nah, I have just arrived".

It may help to realize that *only* is related to the word *one* (you can think of it as the "adverb" form of *one*).

*Just* has several meanings, one of them is used to express that almost no time has passed between an action and now.  You can't substitute *only* when this meaning is used.

> I just got home.  Let me take my coat off and then we'll talk

If you really want to use *only* you have to include a time expression.

> I only got home a second ago.  Let me take my coat off and then we'll talk.

*Just* can also be used to express that you don't want or don't want to do anything except X.

> I just/only want to go home = I don't want to do anything else except go home.
>
> I just/only want some candy = I don't want anything else except candy.

*Just* however might be more typically used if:

- someone is threatening you and you're saying you want to do something to escape, or
- you are being accused of something and are trying to explain you want to do something else instead.

> I just want to go home (you're scared)
>
> I was just trying to look at it (someone's accusing you of stealing)

*Just* is definitely a weird word in English.  Google lists 6 definitions and they all mean very different things.  The meaning of *only* is only one possible meaning of *just*.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I got much better understanding. Btw, what does "one" in *It may help to realize that only is related to the word **one** (you can think of it as the "adverb" form of **one**).*

Comment: I only just got home?