# Should I use simple present or simple past in a tiny story to illustrate a scenario of the usage of some words?

Tags: grammar

I made up a tiny story to illustrate a scenario of the usage of "just" in a post ([In terms of meaning "recently", what is the difference between just & only?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/238313/95044)).

> there is an appointment at a caffe, I am late for 10 minutes, when I arrive at the caffe, my friend is already in there. I say: "I'm so sorry! I am late". My friend says: "Nah, I am just arrived".

Should I use simple present, simple past or other else tense in this kind of stories?

Answer (score 1):

First, here are the stories in past and present:

present:

> *Imagine* there is an appointment at a caffe. I am *10 minutes* late *arriving* at the caffe. My friend is already in there. I say: "I'm so sorry! I am late". My friend says: "No problem, I just arrived".

past:

> There was an appointment at a caffe. I was *10 minutes* late *arriving* at the caffe, and my friend was already in there. I said: "I'm so sorry! I am late". My friend said: "No problem, I just arrived".

Which tense is better?

If it's a hypothetical, imaginary, and very brief story which is *just to illustrate the use of a word*, then the present tense seems like a pretty good choice.

If it's a longer imaginary story, which is meant to tell a story, then the past tense is preferable.

If it's a true story that actually happened, you have two choices.
- the past tense (obviously), or
- the historical present or historic present, also called dramatic present or narrative present, which is the employment of the present tense when narrating past events.

---

In summary, for exactly the type of scenario you are asking about, the present tense seems like a good idea.