# Would "fabricate" indicates "on bad purpose" or "on bad manners" in terms of meaning of "make up"?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

To give some background for a post ([Should I use simple present or simple past in a tiny story to illustrate a scenario of the usage of some words?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/238319/95044)) I said

> I *made up* a tiny story to illustrate a scenario of the usage of "just" in a post ([In terms of meaning "recently", what is the difference between just & only?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/238313/95044)).

I was trying to use the word "fabricate" instead of "make up" though, I was worried "fabricate" indicates meaning like "on bad purpose" or "on bad manners", so I didn't choose it there.

So, would "fabricate" indicates meaning like "on bad purpose" or "on bad manners"?

Comment: As an alternative,  you could use _created_ instead of _made up_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Fabricate" doesn't *always* have a negative meaning. Let's substitute it in your example sentence to see:

> I *fabricated* a tiny story to illustrate a scenario of the usage of "just" in a post.

Here, the reader won't automatically assume some negative meaning in the word, mostly because it's hard to imagine how you making up a sentence to illustrate usage of "just" could be some nefarious thing.

---

However, in practice, the word usually is reserved for scenarios where you want to specifically imply that the person doing the fabricating did so for nefarious purposes. [This is definition 1b in Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fabricate):

> to make up for the purpose of deception

"Make up" sounds much more natural and is more colloquial for the example sentence you gave.